# Is SpeechSynthesisUtterance with SSML a fairy tale?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis, ssml

Why is [SpeechSynthesisUtterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) so buggy?
Is the [SSML XML format](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/) a fairy tale?

The code goes something like this ...

```
      var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
      var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(txt);
      speech.rate = 0.8;
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
```

Please take a look at this demo site to see the state of affairs in various browsers and devices:

https://www.cqrl.in/dev/speak.html

(all the code is in the HTML file)

The `onboundary` chasing seems too fast compared to the voice...
Or may be there is some bug in my code?
My Ubunutu Chrome doesn't respond to `onboundary` at all but Windows one does.
Of course, none of them respond to SSML tags at all (but some of them are even crazy enough to speak-up the XML tags)...

Answer (score 4):

It still isn't implemented:
https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/10
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88072

The final comment on the first thread seems to say that they still have no ideaa how to implement SSML.

So yes, for a while it's just a fairy tale...